# How to check 2 checkboxes together?

Tags: javascript

For example, if I check the first checkbox then the second checkbox will also checked, the second checkbox is dependent on the first checkbox. I have 8checkboxes so they are 4 pairs and in array format. How could I do that?

Comment: Add some code please.

Comment: bind a handler on first checkbox change event. That handler should set second checkbox's *checked* property according to the first checkbox. Have you tried it?

Comment: <input type='checkbox' onclick='handleClick(this);'> what's the problem?

Comment: @nni6 No obtrusive JavaScript please.

Comment: @pavlo oh, right. My example actually is a "bad practice".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways doing that. The following is just one of these possibilities (see also this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BZB3X/)). But will not work in older IEs because of not supporting addEventListener natively. Details on that can be found here: [addEventListener on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/elemento.addEventListener)

```
<input id="first-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="first">
<input id="second-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="second">

document.getElementById("first-checkbox").addEventListener("change", function() {
  document.getElementById("second-checkbox").checked = this.checked;
});
```

A note: this points to "second checkbox is dependent on the first" but will not work vice versa. You could save the element references adding a click handler to both of them and then set the current checked state to the not clicked checkbox. Also this code will reset the checked state on the second checkbox if the first is unchecked. (I was not sure on reading your question what you exactly want to do.)

Comment: Bind to the `change` event instead of the `click` event. The state of the checkbox can also be changed with the keyboard.

Comment: Also you could avoid traversing the DOM by caching your selectors.

Comment: @Pavlo `document.getElementById` is one of the most efficient DOM selection methods. Using it has a negligible impact on performance.

Comment: It depends on implementation. Even if it is fast, there is no point to look it up every time.

Comment: by the way . i have 8 checkboxes and they're paired and in array format .. how could I do that ? sorry I forgot to tell it that I have 8 array checkboxes :) . tnx for your sharing of your good idea . God Bless .

Comment: @Pavlo: true. I did not proposed the most performant solution. I just wanted to show how to solve it. Of course you could save the DOM lookups. =)

Comment: @user2825509 I would use event delegation for that... by watching for bubbling change events and determine the source (by adding a className or a data- attribute) - [change event](http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html) - Note that this also might be a bit difficult if you have to support old browsers (where the event does not bubble)

Answer (score 0):

To bind two checkboxes together you can receive the identity of the checkbox element—as well as its boolean-checked-value—via `this`. Update the other checkbox after checking what `this` is:

```js
const chBox1 = document.getElementById( "chBox1" )
const chBox2 = document.getElementById( "chBox2" )
const box    = document.getElementById( "box" )

chBox1.addEventListener( "change", colorBox )
chBox2.addEventListener( "change", colorBox )

function colorBox(){        
  if ( this == chBox1 )     // IF THIS (ie WHAT WAS CLICKED) IS chBox1
       { chBox2.checked = this.checked }  // UPDATE chBox2
  else { chBox1.checked = this.checked }  // ELSE UPDATE chBox1 
                            // AND THE FUNCTIONALITY:
  if ( this.checked )
       { box.classList.add( "red" )}
  else { box.classList.remove( "red" )}
}
```

```css
#box {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 1px solid black;
 }
 #box.red {
   background-color: red;
 }
```

```html
<label for="chBox1">color Box!</label>
<input id="chBox1" type="checkbox" name="first">

<div id='box'></div>

<label for="chBox2">ditto!</label>
<input id="chBox2" type="checkbox" name="second">
```